# How to convert psd file which contains search box to html search box?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, photoshop

This is about converting psd file to html.When converting from psd to html, I am getting an image which incudes a search box also.How to enter text to that search box which is image after downloading from photoshop as **save as web**?

Is there any other things I need to do while converting from psd to html?

is there any other softwares to convert from psd to html like adobe photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

That is how its meant to be. The template is saved as a PSD file and not a HTML file.There are many tools that help you do this.

***1)*** [PSD2HTML](https://www.psd2html.com/)

***2)*** [Pixel2HTML](https://pixel2html.com/)

However most of them are **paid** services

But as always you can check out some great youtube tutorials:

***1)*** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTYHY2zpYEg

***2)*** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMQ_OPk-eWI